# How to call a function outside of the current module?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to be able to call a function from one module to another. In my case, i'm calling a module function from a PowerPoint Object.

Here is my code:
Slide10:

```
data.save ("2")
```

Module1:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Public savePath As String
Public Static Function save(levelNumber As String)
    With fso.CreateTextFile(savePath & "\data.txt", True)
        .Write ("<continueFromLevel>" & levelNumber & "</continueFromLevel>")
    End With
End Function
```

I tried `Option Explicit` in Module1:

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Public savePath As String
Public Static Function save(levelNumber As String)
    With fso.CreateTextFile(savePath & "\data.txt", True)
        .Write ("<continueFromLevel>" & levelNumber & "</continueFromLevel>")
    End With
End Function
```

but no luck.
I also tried `Option Private Module` in Module1 and using `Call data.save "2"` at Slide10

```
Module1:

Option Private Module
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Public savePath As String
Public Static Function save(levelNumber As String)
    With fso.CreateTextFile(savePath & "\data.txt", True)
        .Write ("<continueFromLevel>" & levelNumber & "</continueFromLevel>")
    End With
End Function

Slide10:

Call data.save "2"
```

I EVEN tried calling the function without the `Call` statement and without the parenthesis:
Slide10:

```
data.save "2"
```

But all I get in return is an "Invalid Outside Procedure" error.

EDIT 1:`data` is actually `Module1`.

Comment: If the module is named `Module1` then you need to say `Module1.save`

Comment: Also, regarding `fso`, it looks like you will run into "Run-time error '91' Object variable not set". You might be missing a line `Set fso = ...`

Comment: `data.save "2"` is where exactly - is it part of a larger Sub/Function ?  It can't be all by itself (hence "Invalid Outside Procedure")

Comment: And what is `data`?

Comment: You may have noticed ```fso``` is a ```FileSystemObject```. In this case, it is not necessary to use ```Set fso = ...```.

Comment: @FunThomas , here is ```data```:
```Option Explicit
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Public savePath As String
Public Static Function save(levelNumber As String)
    With fso.CreateTextFile(savePath & "\data.txt", True)
        .Write ("<continueFromLevel>" & levelNumber & "</continueFromLevel>")
    End With
End Function```

Comment: ```Module1``` is actually ```data```

Comment: `Sub foo()`, `data.save "2"`, `End Sub`.

Comment: @BigBen i even tried that and it dosent work

Comment: I don't understand you, all modules functions are public by default, can be called without class.dot syntax. Why not all Save "2" simply ?

Comment: Even tried that without the dot and it still does not work

Comment: You could rename your Save() function to a more specific name, like testSave, and call testSave again to try.

Comment: does not work too